# java - Перевод unix даты в формат hh:mm

Tags: java, android, unix

Уже час мучаюсь,  никак не получается. Нужно перевести unix в часы и минуты

Comment: а правильно ли я понимаю, что вам нужно получить значение часов и минут из Unix Timestamp? Или вам просто надо перевести секунды в часы и минуты?

Comment: Все получилось, дело в том, что со стороны сервера уже происходила отправка в миллисекундах) А я не знал и умножал) Все верно отвечали )

Comment: Тогда это не Unix Time, а просто милисекунды

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для перевода даты\времени в нужный формат, можете использовать [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Обратите внимание, что `Unix Timestamp` измеряется в **секундах** в то время, как `Date` в `Java` - в **милисекундах**. То есть, для того, чтобы перевести `Unix Timestamp` в `Date`, изначально нужно `Unix Timestamp` умножить на 1000.

Итого, чтобы привести ваш `Unix Timestamp` в нужный формат 24 часов, надо:

```
String result = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date(unixTime * 1000));
```

Обратите внимание, что `"HH:mm"` переведет в 24-часовой формат, а `"hh:mm"` - в 12-часовой. Подробнее о форматировании вы можете узнать в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm").format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
```

Comment: А куда же сам unix в формате long писать?

Comment: вместое System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: В 12 часовом формате. Как в 24?

Comment: Ничего не получается